# Help needed getting set of child object IDs in a trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I have a set which I want to populate with child record ID's

```
    set <custom_object_name__c> ids = new set <custom_object_name__c>();
    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new)
        ids.add(opp.custom_object_names__r); // <-- I NEED HELP HERE!
```

When I run this I get:

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject:
>   External entry point

If I were to query for the exact same thing using SOQL, it would look this:

```
Select (Select Id From custom_object_names__r) From Opportunity o
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?!

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In triggers only the immediate fields of the object are populated; relationship fields are not.

So you will have to query to find the child object IDs yourself in the trigger:

```
Set<Id> conIds = new Set<Id>();
for (custom_object_name__c con : [
        select Id
        from custom_object_name__c
        where Opportunity__c in :Trigger.newMap.keySet()
        ]) {
    conIds.add(con.Id);
}
```

This can also be done without the Apex loop by using the [map constructor](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_ctor) that automatically uses the ID value as the key and the SObject as the value for a list of SObjects:

```
Set<Id> conIds = new Map<Id, custom_object_name__c>([
        select Id
        from custom_object_name__c
        where Opportunity__c in :Trigger.newMap.keySet()
        ]).keySet();
```

Comment: I didn't know you can do that with maps. That's great, thanks so much for your help.